# How do I get one week list from SQL Server database by using a statement in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to know if it is possible to set this?

This is from SQL Server.

My logical explanation is

VB.NET:

```
If "Date_Needed between `getdate()` And `dateadd(day,7,getdate())` "
Then
   `DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red`
End If
```

or

```
If Date_needed = (1 weeklist) from (Today's Date)
Then
   `DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red`
End If
```

`Date_needed` is a column value fetched from SQL Server.

If the system reads the datagridview with today's date to one week list the selected rows in datagridview will turn red forecolor highlight.

```
Select *
From PRF_Form
Where Date_Needed Between getdate() And Dateadd(day, 7, getdate())
```

Comment: the code should be like this i guess?
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    If dt.Rows(i)(9).ToString = Date.Now And DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7) Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If
                Next

Answer (score 0):

I would have added a column to the returned result set to indicate if the row falls into the 'NeededDate' selection. Let my database do the heavy lifting there, and just rely on the VB.NET side of things to style based upon the values returned from the query.

But, first, I want to point out an issue you made in your own answer to this question. The "&" in VB.NET is a string concatenation operator not a logical AND operation. & will implicitly cast objects to string when used.

So, this line in your response

```
Date.Now & DateAdd(intervaltype, days, secondDate)
```

would have generated a string that looked something like:  **April 13, 2019April 5,2019**
Which is not good for date comparisons. Additionally, it would not throw a compiler error, because it will automatically convert the date object on the left side of the compare operator to string, since the value on the right side was a string.

It's been stated before, but you do need all of the elements in an actual DATE type in order to compare dates.

So try something like this

```
 Dim startdate As Date
 If Not Date.TryParse(DateString, startDate) Then startDate = Date.Now
 Dim days As Double = 7
 Dim secondDate As Date
 secondDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, days, startdate)
 For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
     Dim checkDate As Date = Date.Parse(dt.Rows(i)(5).ToString)
     If checkDate <= Date.Now AndAlso checkDate >= secondDate Then
           DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
     End If
 Next
```

Note the "AndAlso" operator.  This is similar to an `And` operator, but will only check the compare option to the right of it if the compare operator to the left of the `AndAlso` returns true.

Comment: i also try this one but nothing happens. no red highlights on the said week before the deadline